# Getting right information from sql server I need to find a way to pull the current interest rate for accounts see the details below

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
l_acctrfefno    interest_rate   ExpirationDate  interest_type
6983400 6.99000000  NULL    0
6983500 6.99000000  NULL    0
6984400 8.99000000  NULL    0
6984400 0.00000000  2022-09-28 00:00:00.000 7
6985600 0.00000000  NULL    0
6988500 9.99000000  NULL    0
6988500 0.00000000  2022-10-01 00:00:00.000 7
6988600 9.99000000  NULL    0
6988700 5.99000000  NULL    0
6988800 8.99000000  NULL    0
```

I need to find out the current interest rate for an acctrefno.  the below SQL pulls the interest rates form a loan, but some new can have an introductory rate, which will have an expiration, and then a current rate.  see acctrefno 69844 and 69885 in the below query.  I need to return the current rate for each loan. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` and filtering:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by l_acctrfefno
                                order by coalesce(expiration_date, '9999-01-01')
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
      where expiration_date is null or getdate() < expiration_date 
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```